# Jquery text animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking everywhere for a free version(or similar plugin) of the following jquery text animator, but I can't find any. There are so many free snippets of great jquery plugins, why can't I find any for a text animator like this one? http://codecanyon.net/item/textfx-a-jquery-text-animation-tool/full_screen_preview/309565?ref=lvraa

I really did a lot of research, an this one is the closest to my need. I just want an unobtrusive text animator for text content on my web page that should draw the attention of the viewer.

Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a animation of some div. You can do it yourself. 
First: break a string into an array of div (I suggest that you use jquery)

```
var s = 'Hello world';
var animationcanvas = $('<div />');
for (i = 0; i< s.length; i++){
   animationcanvas.append('<div>' + s[i] + '</div>');
}
```

then think of some animate and do it using `jquery.animate`
gut luck

Comment: thanks mate, appreciate. And thank you for not being a jerk about it like the two commentators above.